# Want to browse Meta with the upcoming SuperUser stylesheet/logo?

Tags: discussion, greasemonkey

Want to browse Meta with the upcoming SuperUser stylesheet/logo?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           not-so super user
// @namespace      soflow
// @include        *meta.stackoverflow.com*
// ==/UserScript==

for( i = 0; (l = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i]); i++ ) {
    if( l.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("style") >= 0 ) l.disabled = true;
}

var link = window.document.createElement('link');
link.rel = 'stylesheet';
link.type = 'text/css';
link.href = 'http://dev.superuser.com/content/all.css?v=3959';
document.getElementsByTagName("HEAD")[0].appendChild(link);

var logoImage = document.getElementById("hlogo").getElementsByTagName("img")[0];

logoImage.src = "http://dev.superuser.com/content/img/su/logo.png";
logoImage.width = "250";
logoImage.height = "60";
```

[image]

Comment: How'd you do it?! I DEMAND TO KNOW.

Comment: He already has 2k rep!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Paolo: I think that qualifies him for the Hacker badge :)

Comment: Way to rollback to a sentence that makes no sense at all.

Comment: I feel like I should start screaming "EDIT WAR!" while the rest of Meta crowds around. Sort of like grade school.

Comment: Eric: If you do I will imagine myself punching you in the junk so hard that I will hope you feel it.

Comment: @Eric: What edit war? We don't edit war anymore. We make valid edits, people rollback because they are uncomfortable with the rules of the site, and we inform the mods. No war needed.

Comment: @Rich: Thank goodness. That had all the inklings of one. @TXI: Please stay as far away from my junk as possible.

Comment: @Eric: Where are you seeing all of these edit wars you are so afraid of?

Comment: So, when are you just gonna change your user name to Greasemonkey? ;)

Comment: @gnovice Hehe. I've abandoned nicknames long ago :)

Comment: @gnovice Although "Curious George" is interestingly relevant to GreaseMONKEY-solutions that dig into Superuser :)

Comment: @Rich: Afraid isn't the right word. Cynical is probably the right one. What with all the grand-standing and righteousness and whatnot. Also, I believe Jonathan created the "Ignore User" GreaseMonkey script just after one of thems.

Comment: @Jonathan, please keep the title rich wrote.  It is better than the old one.

Comment: @jjnguy - Rich didn't write that. I did. He merely migrated it from the body to the title.

Comment: fair enough                 .

Comment: (After I wrote the body).... lol

Comment: @Jonathan: I think you've already GreaseMonkey'd yourself up a nickname that will be hard to get rid of. :)

Comment: @Eric: So you saw one edit war and now automatically comment every time you see an edit about the ensuing edit war?

Comment: @Rich: Yes. All of my judgements are snap ones. Because I think with my gut.

Comment: @Jonathan: is there a way for the script to remember a setting?  Say that you had a drop down and had selected option 2.  When the page reloads, is there a way to keep option 2 set?

Comment: @Eric: I figured.

Comment: It looks 'shopped, I can see the pixels.

Comment: @RSolberg I believe GM  has some built-in storage. That, or you could probably set a cookie.

Answer (score 7):

I have to say, I'm *really* liking the new theme. From the slight blue highlight for interesting questions to the purple comment scores, I think that Jeff has a winner here. I like it so much that I don't want to go back to the cold gray that's the default here.

Comment: I agree. I like the lighter colors. Very uplifting. Although, I must say that I'd love to see native-support of user-themes too so I don't have to see the style-sheets swap each request :)

Comment: After spending so much time on Meta recently, it's going to be hard getting used to colors again.

Comment: Colors?  What are those again?  That's like, when something is *extra* gray, right?

Comment: I've been using the SO CSS since the first day I came here. The grey was way to bland and distracting. I have no idea how you cope with it.

Answer (score 3):

Good find! But that black-backed "0 answers" thing sticks out like a sore thumb. Can you post some other pages as well (viewing a question, user list, etc)?

Comment: Shouldn't 0 answers stick out like a sore thumb?

Comment: Sure, but I think that in keeping with the rest of the site, they should be red text on a white background

Answer (score 3):

You'd better Greasemonkey up a way for me to get in there or I will cry.

Comment: To be fair, you will cry either way.

Comment: That is completely irrelevant.

Comment: It's my answer and I'll cry if I want to. Cry if I want to. Cry if I want to. You would cry too if it happened to you.

Comment: @TheTXI: I thought we weren't going to bring up the pony incident anymore?

Comment: Rich B: That's no need for you to be ashamed of your relationship with Sparkles.

Comment: Now it's Rich's turn to cry, Rich's turn to cry, Rich's turn to cry.  'Cause Sparkles came back, to me.

Comment: Wow Joel. Now I am truly disturbed.

Answer (score 3):

Can you make this with a drop down so we can pick a theme for meta, so, sf, and su?

I don't know if I would change the logo in the script, but the colors, amazing!

Comment: I like having the logo changed - it really completes the design. It would be nice to have a dropdown though.

Comment: I guess I don't want the site to lose its complete identity...  I will use this for all of the sites in the triliogy and change everything to this stylesheet.  So having the logos in place is a plus so I know which site I'm really on.

Answer (score 2):

I've modified your script a weeeee bit and combined it with a modified navigation one...  It'll default the theme to whatever the site's theme is, but clicking the colored boxes at the top of the screen changes themes accordingly...

```
function changeTheme(url)
{
    for( i = 0; (l = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i]); i++ ) {
        if( l.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("style") >= 0 ) l.disabled = true;
    }

    var link = window.document.createElement('link');
    link.rel = 'stylesheet';
    link.type = 'text/css';
    link.href = url;
    document.getElementsByTagName("HEAD")[0].appendChild(link);
}

(function(){
  function GM_wait() {
    if(typeof unsafeWindow.jQuery == 'undefined') { 
      window.setTimeout(GM_wait,100); 
    } else { 
      $ = unsafeWindow.jQuery; letsJQuery(); 
    }
  }
  GM_wait();
  function letsJQuery() {
    $('#hlinks')
      .prepend('<span class="link-separator"> | </span>')
      .prepend("<a href='http://meta.stackoverflow.com'><img src='http://meta.stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico' title='Visit Meta Stack Overflow' style='padding:1px'></a>")
      .prepend('<span class="link-separator"> | </span>')
      .prepend("<a href='http://www.serverfault.com'><img src='http://serverfault.com/favicon.ico' title='Visit ServerFault' style='padding:1px'></a>")
      .prepend('<span class="link-separator"> | </span>')
      .prepend("<a href='http://dev.superuser.com'><img src='http://dev.superuser.com/favicon.ico' title='Visit SuperUser' style='padding:1px'></a>")
      .prepend('<span class="link-separator"> | </span>')
      .prepend("<a href='http://www.stackoverflow.com'><img src='http://stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico' title='StackOverflow' style='padding:1px'></a>")
      .prepend('<span class="link-separator"> | </span>')
      .prepend("<a id='mtheme' href='#' style='position:relative;top:1px;display:inline-block;width:10px;height:10px;background:#ccc;margin-right:1px;' title='Meta Theme'><span style='display:none'>meta.stackoverflow</span></a>")
      .prepend("<a id='sftheme' href='#' style='position:relative;top:1px;display:inline-block;width:10px;height:10px;background:#c99;margin-right:7px' title='Server Fault Theme'><span style='display:none'>serverfault</span></a>")
      .prepend("<a id='sutheme' href='#' style='position:relative;top:1px;display:inline-block;width:10px;height:10px;background:#00ADED;margin-right:7px' title='Super User Theme'><span style='display:none'>superuser</span></a>")
      .prepend("<a id='sotheme' href='#' style='position:relative;top:1px;display:inline-block;width:10px;height:10px;background:#f60;margin-right:7px' title='Stack Overflow Theme'><span style='display:none'>stackoverflow</span></a>")

    $('#sotheme').bind("click", function() {
        changeTheme('http://stackoverflow.com/content/all.css');
        return false;
    });
    $('#sftheme').bind("click", function() {
        changeTheme('http://serverfault.com/content/all.css');
        return false;
    });
    $('#mtheme').bind("click", function() {
        changeTheme('http://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/all.css');
        return false;
    });
    $('#sutheme').bind("click", function() {
        changeTheme('http://dev.superuser.com/content/all.css');
        return false;
    });
  }
})();
```

The ServerFault theme is currently not working very well... Not sure why...  I would also like to figure out a way for the GM script to remember what your last theme selection was so it could persist for future clicks.

Comment: You misspelled it "servervault" :-)

Comment: That would explain sooooooo much!

Comment: And the typo has been corrected...

Comment: you can also take out the ?v=3959 if you want

Comment: out of curiosity, what does the ?v=#### actually do?  Is that a version of some kind of the doc?

Comment: It's the SVN version, and it's used to get browsers to fetch a new version of the CSS if there are changes made.

Answer (score 0):

*Anything* would look like an improvement after looking at the metaSO theme for a few days. :)